# Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of null on discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So i'm a fairly new and keep getting this error: "Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of null" in my logs. Its basically trying check if the role has manage channels perms, and then removes it. Any help would be appreciated.

Sorry if this makes no sense, i am deadly tired.

```
if(role.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) {
    con(`${role.name} - Manage Channels Permission`.green)
    role.setPermissions(0).catch(e => con(`${getNow('time')} - [ERROR] Role too high. (${e})`.red))
    }
  });
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `role` defined? What gets printed to your console if you do `console.dir(role)` immediately before your `if` statement?

Comment: your `role` is undefined. probably searched for a role by name and got an empty result

Comment: @esqew I get this https://imgur.com/a/BVzTaly - and also a TypeError: role.hasPermission is not a function afterwards. Heres the code just before all of this too: for (id of dm) bot.users.cache.get(id).send(cd)

Comment: Have you reviewed [the documentation for the `Role` class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role)? It indicates by omission that `Role` doesn't have any method `hasPermission()`. Can you elaborate as to how you reached the conclusion that this would not be the case?